# Run for loop multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple app that display random number on click and display the result on the list after generation.

What I'm trying to do is to make a number of loop base from the user input.

Ex. I input 5, it will display 5 sets of random numbers

2 3 3 2 1

4 1 2 3 4

3 4 5 1 6

1 9 22 45 5

1 33 22 11 2

Also the displaying on result is one by one.

the end result is something like [this](https://www.random.org/quick-pick/?tickets=5&lottery=5x69.1x26)

I tried interval but doesn't work.
Hope you understand me.

```js
$('input').val(1);
$('button').click(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var lotto = [];
    var results = [];
    setTimeout(function() {
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
      lotto.push(r);

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('ul li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').text(lotto[i]);
      }, 200);
      if (lotto.length == 5) {
        results.push(lotto);
        setTimeout(function() {
          for (let x = 0; x < results.length; x++) {
            $('.results').append('<li>' + results[x] + '</li>');
          }
        }, 500);
      }
    }, 500 * i);
  }
});
```

```css
ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<input type="text"><button>Display</button>

<ul class="results"></ul>
```

Comment: I wonder why, I got negative.

Comment: Maybe because it is not clear what you are asking. BTW I am not the downvoter

Comment: Can you please elaborate the issue you are facing?

Comment: ex. I input 3, it will display 43512,34531,32455

Comment: You mean 5*5 matrix?

Comment: @CoolJK I'm not sure what you mean sir,

Comment: i mean when you input 5 you want total 25 random numbers right?

Comment: @CoolJK, only five results sir, (22 33 44 55 66) this one is equal to a set of random numbers, if I put 5 it will generate another 4 sets of random numbers.

Comment: @Mark ok got it

Comment: @CoolJK please check it sir [desired output](https://www.random.org/quick-pick/?tickets=5&lottery=5x69.1x26)